# Sitecore Link is not adding attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I am using Sitecore and using VS2010 (Version 4). I am adding attributes from the code behind according to the tab index user goes to:

```
Link hlTabLink;
i = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
hlTabLink = e.Item.FindControl("hlTabLink") as Link;
hlTabLink.Target = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(i);
hlTabLink.DataSource = i.Paths.FullPath;
hlTabLink.Field = "Title";
String liContainerId;
switch (hlTabLink.TabIndex) //Switch case statements for the tab navigation. 
            {
                case 0:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
                    hlTabLink.Attributes.Add("class", liContainerId);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
                    hlTabLink.Attributes.Add("class", liContainerId);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label last";
                    hlTabLink.Attributes.Add("class", liContainerId);
                    break;
            }
```

This is the markup of .ascx control:

```
<div class="tab-panels" id="TabbedPanels1">
    <ul id="Tab-labels">
       <asp:Repeater ID="rptTab" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTab_ItemBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <sc:Link ID = "hlTabLink" Field = "scTabLink" runat ="server"></sc:Link>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
```

My markup is looking like this after rendering:

```
<div class="tab-panels" id="TabbedPanels1">
    <ul id="Tab-labels">

                <li>
                    Overview
                </li>

                <li>
                    Why Me
                </li>

    </ul>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't look like **hlTabLink** is added to the page anywhere.  Also, shouldn't you instantiate it at some point? Link hlTabLink = new Link()?

Comment: what is Link ? i first time saw it. which asp.net version you are using ?

Comment: I guess the switch condition is not true for any of the cases. Why don't you add a default case and then see if the attribute is populated or not?

Comment: He is showing the output, not the .ascx markup.  And FindControl is returning the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Sitecore namespace, Link is an extension of the ASP:Hyperlink control.  Use CssClass
to set the attributes of the anchor tag:

```
hlTabLink.CssClass = liContainerId;
```

Comment: Nice.  This probably also persists between post-backs, where manually adding something to the .Attributes class will not.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you aren't doing anything wrong... it's just that the Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link object isn't bothering to render your extra attributes.  Take a peek at the code using Reflector to confirm.

Replace the Sitecore Link objects with HyperLink.  It appears you are not doing anything here that warrants using the Sitecore control over the standard ASP.NET object.

Comment: Yeah after hearing that the case statements are in fact getting hit, I'd say this is the next step to take.

Comment: Seems like it. I am gonna give a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what comes back from

```
hlTabLink = e.Item.FindControl("hlTabLink") as Link;
```

it's hard to say exactly what's happening, but I'm guessing that none of the case statements are hitting and because you don't have a default case, no class is getting added. Try adding this to your switch and see what happens:

```
         default:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
                    hlTabLink.Attributes.Add("class", liContainerId);
                    break;
```

Comment: Switch statements are hitting. I checked it.